# C#. Разрешение зависимости через DI Autofac, 2 разных объекта на 1 зависимость

Tags: c#, .net, di, autofac

Здравствуйте, возможно неточно сформулировал вопрос, попытаюсь описать в коде.

```
public class XmlSerializeTableRecRepository : ITrainTableRecRepository
{
    public XmlSerializeTableRecRepository(string connection)
    {        
    }
    //Members...    
}

public interface ITrainTableRecRepository : IGenericDataRepository<TrainTableRec>
{
}


/// <summary>
/// регистрируем сопоставление типов
/// </summary>
private static void RegisterType(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
   builder.RegisterType<XmlSerializeTableRecRepository>().As<ITrainTableRecRepository>()
          .WithParameters(new List<Parameter> { new NamedParameter("connection", @"TrainTableMain.xml") });
}
```

Нужно внедрить зависимость от репозитория (IGenericDataRepository).
таблица хранится в XML файлах, непосредственная реализация репозитория работает с данными через сериализацию, но возможны другие типы хранилища, для этого и есть ITrainTableRecRepository.

Пока данные хранились в 1 XML файле ("TrainTableMain.xml"), все работало как по учебнику).
Но понадобилось параллельно через удаленный HTTP сервис получать данные и складывать их в репозиторий, только в другой ("TrainTableRemoute.xml").

Т.е. нужно чтобы DI создал объекты так
для удаленного сервиса:

```
var rep= new XmlSerializeTableRecRepository("TrainTableRemoute.xml");
```

для локального сервиса:

```
var rep= new XmlSerializeTableRecRepository("TrainTableMain.xml");
```

Но как мне зарегистрировать типы для такого соответствия, если 1 раз уже заданно `ITrainTableRecRepository -> XmlSerializeTableRecRepository("TrainTableMain.xml")?

Или это нарущает основы работы контейнера и придется делать фейковый тип для второго объекта?

Или просто передавать строку подключения через public свойство в сам репозиторий, после его создания через DI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте [именованные сервисы](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html):

```
builder.RegisterType<XmlSerializeTableRecRepository>()
    .Named<ITrainTableRecRepository>("Main")
    .WithParameter("connection", "TrainTableMain.xml");
builder.RegisterType<XmlSerializeTableRecRepository>()
    .Named<ITrainTableRecRepository>("Remote")
    .WithParameter("connection", "TrainTableRemote.xml");
```

Но магии, конечно же, не получится: для всех кто использует этот репозиторий вам придется явно указывать какой из репозиториев ему нужен:

```
builder.RegisterType<Foo>()
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ITrainTableRecRepository),
        (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<ITrainTableRecRepository>("Remote")
    ));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Почитал по ссылке, но ваш пример не понял. А резолвить как?

Comment: @Aldmi я же написал как

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за помощь, написал в своем ответе как получилось у меня.

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь что не понял ответ Pavel Mayorov, сделал вот так.

```
    //REGISTER
                builder.RegisterType<XmlSerializeTableRecRepository>().Named<ITrainTableRecRepository>("Local")
                    .WithParameters(new List<Parameter> { new NamedParameter("connection", @"TrainTableMain.xml") });


                builder.RegisterType<XmlSerializeTableRecRepository>().Named<ITrainTableRecRepository>("RemoteCis")
                    .WithParameters(new List<Parameter> { new NamedParameter("connection", @"TrainTableRemoteCis.xml") });

    //RESOLVE       
using (var scope = AutofacConfig.Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
                    {
                        var repResolve = scope.ResolveNamed<ITrainTableRecRepository>("Local");

                        var repResolve2 = scope.ResolveNamed<ITrainTableRecRepository>("RemoteCis");
                    }
```

Comment: Зачем вам вообще Autofac с таким подходом?

Comment: При именованном резолве смысл теряется, но вся структура программы придерживается DI, для однотипности. Ну и ITrainTableRecRepository может иметь другую зависимость (другая система хранения), при сохранении именования ("Local", "RemoteCis"), тогда вызывающий код остается тот же и мы просто меняем реализацию репозитория.

Comment: А как бы вы сделали, просто вручную передавали в конструктор зависимости?

Comment: Зачем вручную, если Autofac умеет это сам делать?

Comment: В данном проекте UI, это WinForms приложение, поэтому RESOLVE  не автоматический как на ASP net. Или я что то не понимаю?

Comment: У вас что, весь код в одном классе написан? В таком случае зачем вам Autofac?

Comment: Нет, регистрация в корне компоновки (Program.cs) до загрузки UI. Проект бизнес логики использует сервисы, UI проект использует бизенсс логику подставляя туда нужные зависимости.